# Get all items of some other items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I will give an example:

```
Books.find(THIS_FIND_MAY_GET_MORE_THAN_ONE_BOOK).pages.all
```

I am expecting a set of pages... Every page returned should be contained in at least one book. Otherwise it shouldn't be in the set. How can I get such a set?

My intuitive idea was looping over the books and then add every time, but i guess there may be a faster way (databasewise), as I am not interested in the books. I don't want to introduce further database links as I think they may lead to a inconsistent database.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get all of the pages for each book...

```
books=Books.find(:all)
```

...will give you an array of books.  Then you can loop over every book to get its pages...

```
books.each do |book|
   puts book.pages
end
```

This assumes you have setup a relation between books and pages where each book has many pages and each page belongs to a book.

Comment: if that is what you want, remember to include the :pages model in your find to eagerly load the association and avoid extra database requests.

Comment: that would give the expected result (i trust) but i hoped for a nicer solution. imagine i would need some of the books of some rooms... then i would need two loops. but i guess this is faster than a "reverse" approach as proposed by SpyrosP. Thanks for your answers

Comment: if you need the books of some rooms, you could get rooms.books. If things start getting a bit messy with associations, it might be a good idea to use and combine scopes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure on what you really want to do, but since you want pages instead of books, why not use Page.find_by_book_id or by whatever else you want and pass an array with the book ids for instance.

If this is not what you really want, could you please provide some more information on what you want to achieve ? Maybe a scope can work for you, maybe you can write some more info so that i can help you any further.

Comment: thank you for your help here and above. I will read about scopes, maybe they will be useful in te future. In the meanwhile, I will mark the other answer as "the" answer ;)

Answer (score -1):

I guess this is what you want:

```
pages = Page.where("book_id is not NULL")
```